# gephi 0.8.1 issue on Mac X 10.8.2 unable to load libjogl_awt.jnilib

Tags: java, gephi

I'm new to JAVA. I'm on Mac OS X 10.8.2. Using gephi 0.8.1. I get:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_33-b03-424.jdk/Contents/Home
echo $JDK_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_33-b03-424.jdk/Contents/Home
```

gephi libs list:

```
/Applications/gephi.app/Contents/Resources/gephi/gephi/modules/lib/macosx-universal/libjogl.jnilib
/Applications/gephi.app/Contents/Resources/gephi/gephi/modules/lib/macosx-universal/libjogl_awt.jnilib
/Applications/gephi.app/Contents/Resources/gephi/gephi/modules/lib/macosx-universal/libjogl_cg.jnilib
```

Launching gephi from clicking icon won't work, I need to use command line:

```
./gephi --jdkhome /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_33-b03-424.jdk/Contents/Home
```

After this I get 'Unable to load libjogl_awt.jnilib'

Any suggestions on what I can do to fix my JAVA environment -- or at least start gephi? Thx.

UPDATE: As suggested in gephi forums, I've also linked /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_33-b03-424.jdk/Contents and have the 32-bit Java first in Java preferences...

Comment: I'm having the same problem as you unfortunately. I'm on mac lion, and I'm up to date and I have java version "1.6.0_29". Can you tell me how you reinstalled java? because I'm noticing that you're like slightly ahead of me in java...

Comment: Hi Adam, try this troubleshooting suggestion from Gephi on deleting the user dir: http://wiki.gephi.org/index.php/Troubleshooting. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Ah, I actually found that going into the /System...Java/ folder and deleting the java that I had allowed me to use the /Applications/Utilities/java preferences to install anew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to delete the gephi settings folder under /Your_username/Library/Application support/gephi and run it again.

Comment: I had this as a comment, should have listed it as an answer to my own question. Thanks for taking the time to answer, this worked for me to solve this and other issues that popped up.

Answer (score 24):

To run Gephi on OS X Mavericks, just install the Apple's update for Java 6 http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US

If you still have problems it probably means that you have Java 7 installed, and Gephi is using it. You can override that behavior by editing Gephi's config file:

Open /Applications/Gephi.app/Contents/Resources/gephi/etc/gephi.conf and set the `jdkhome` value to:

`jdkhome="/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home"`

Comment: Outstanding, it is definitely not compatible with Java 7 on Mavericks.

Comment: This solution did not work for me on MacOS Big Sur 11.6. I have found no way of getting Java 6 or 7 to work on this version of MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

I re-installed Java for OSX 2012-006 and gephi now works -- don't know why.